# Put all lines that start with X at the end of the file with vi

Tags: vim, vi

What is the best way to take all the lines that begin with the word "define" and paste them at the end of a text file with vi?

For example, if I have:

> define XXX
>
> a
>
> define YYY
>
> b

and I want to get:

> define XXX
>
> a
>
> define YYY
>
> b
>
> define XXX
>
> define YYY

---

*Solutions:*

- In vi, `g/^define/t$` works nicely.
- See below for vim solution.

Comment: Why do you have to use `vi`? Wouldn't it be easier to pre-process the file with some other command?

Comment: I am using vi to edit some code. I would like to include a comment to myself about all the files that the code will produce. It seems strange to use another command if I am already in vi, but I am open to it if that is the best way.

Comment: I'm almost 100% sure that you are not using vi but vim. If that's the case, both solutions are valid. I would go with the built in commands, though.

Comment: The grep approach didn't work until I switched to vim from vi.

Comment: `vi` is most likely an alias or symlink to `vim`, probably launched in `compatible` mode. Always use `vim`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Go<ESC>` (gee, owe, and the escape key) to open up a line at the end of the file, and then enter the characters:

```
!!grep '^define' %<ENTER>
```

That replaces your current line (the one you just opened at the end of the file) with the output of that `grep` command (where `%` is the current file).

You need to ensure the file is saved first since it uses the on-disk copy, not the in-memory copy and keep in mind this is with Vim - older variants of Vi may not have this facility.

Comment: Why the double exclamation?

Comment: @Dimitriy, the first is equivalent to `:.` (switch to `ex` mode and select the current line), the second means replace the selection with the output of the following command. You could just as easily do `:.!grep ...` if you don't mind the extra keystroke.